# How do I control a device that works with Z-Wave JS UI via a published MQTT message?

Tags: mqtt, zwave

I have a setup where I am running a simple mosquito server for MQTT. I then run the Z-Wave JS ui project to interact with my zwave devices. This works great and I see the messages showing up in MQTT for example here is me turning on then back off the light...

```
Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/lastActiveQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876065,"value":1698588451955}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:043

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/lastActiveQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876065,"value":1698588451955}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:043

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/targetValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876077,"value":true}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:053

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/targetValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876077,"value":true}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:054

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/currentValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876079,"value":true}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:054

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/currentValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876079,"value":true}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:055

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/currentValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876094,"value":true}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:068

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/currentValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876094,"value":true}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:068

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/lastActiveQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876316,"value":1698588876093}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:292

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/lastActiveQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876316,"value":1698588876093}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:293

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/lastActiveQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876494,"value":1698588876093}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:467

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/lastActiveQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876494,"value":1698588876093}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:468

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/targetValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876510,"value":false}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:485

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/targetValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876510,"value":false}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:485

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/currentValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876511,"value":false}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:485

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/currentValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876511,"value":false}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:486

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/currentValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876526,"value":false}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:502

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/currentValueQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876526,"value":false}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:503

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/lastActiveQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876743,"value":1698588876526}
2023-10-29 10:14:36:717

Topic: zwave/Bedroom_Light/lastActiveQoS: 0
{"time":1698588876743,"value":1698588876526}
```

Now with this working I would like to publish a message to turn on the light instead of using the web ui. To do this I try to publish the message I saw...

```
zwave/Bedroom_Light/37/0/targetValue
{"time":1698588451956,"value":true}
```

But nothing happens and I don't see the current value message to confirm it was changing. What am I missing how do I get the ZWave device to toggle via MQTT?

After playing a bit it seems to me like Z-Wave-JS-UI isn't properly handling the requests from MQTT. It seems to be publishing to it just fine. Still not sure what I am missing.

Comment: maybe because the timestamp is old ... https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Does the date matter for playback or something if so how old is too old? Made a date in the slight future and tried the same way but did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to read back through [the documentation](https://zwave-js.github.io/zwave-js-ui/#/guide/mqtt?id=set-values), however, it appears there is a `/set` that needs to be added to the topic path so instead of `zwave/Bedroom/Bedroom_Light/37/0/targetValue` is should be `zwave/Bedroom/Bedroom_Light/37/0/targetValue/set`. Also I could leave out the timestamp and just send this...

```
{"value":true}
```

Now it works fine.